# C11 standard guarantees for casting one array type to another

Tags: c, arrays, types, c11

So I have an application where I use a lot of arrays of chars, shorts, ints, and long longs, all unsigned. Rather than allocating space for each and deallocating, my thought is to have a static array of unsigned long longs. I would then cast this as needed as an array of the appropriate type. Is there a way to prove this is compliant with the standard?

I am statically asserting that char, short, int, and long long are of sizes 1, 2, 4, and 8, respectively, and that their alignment requirements do not exceed their sizes. I would like to know if I can prove the validity of my approach with no further static assertions.

EDIT: I thought I'd add that the standard defines object representation as a copy of an object as an array of unsigned char. It seems that this justifies using an unsigned long long array as either that or an unsigned char array, although I cannot absolutely rule out problems associated with using the object representation in context of the object itself rather than in a copy (which is how 6.2.6.1.4 discusses the object representation). This is, however, all I can find, and it does not help at all with the two intermediate integer sizes.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea - what do you hope to achieve by not allocating and de-allocating appropriate arrays for each use case ?

Comment: The application is extremely performance sensitive. This would avoid creating and destroying objects, and it would also keep the working space smaller for cache considerations. I understand that I can reuse dynamically allocated space, but one large space saves calculations of more exact upper bounds on the space needed.

Comment: Sounds like premature optimisation, and effectively all you are doing is overlaying your own memory management scheme on top of the system's. You may also lose out on the system's memory-related optimisations too, e.g. lazy allocation, zero pages, copy-on-write, etc. I suggest writing clean functional code first, and then only apply optimisation hacks later if they prove to be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you're not talking about casting *arrays*.  You're talking about casting *pointers*.

The standard does not guarantee that what you're doing is safe. You can treat an array of `unsigned long long` as, for example, an array of `unsigned char`, but there's no guarantee that you can treat it as an array of `unsigned int`.

Consider a hypothetical implementation with `CHAR_BIT==8`, `sizeof (unsigned int) == 4`, and `sizeof (unsigned long long) == 8`.  Assume `unsigned int` requires strict 4-byte alignment. But the underlying machine has no direct support for 64-bit quantities, so all operations on `unsigned long long` are done in software. Because of this, the required alignment for `unsigned long long` is, let's say, 2 bytes.

So an array of `unsigned long long` might start at an address that's not a multiple of 4 bytes, and therefore you can't safely treat it as an array of `unsigned int`.

I don't suggest that this is a *plausible* implementation. Even if 64-bit integers are implemented in software, it would probably make sense for them to have at least 32-bit alignment. But nothing in what I've described violates the standard; the hypothetical implementation could be conforming.

If you're using a C11 compiler (as indicated by the tag on your question), you could statically assert that

```
_Alignof (unsigned long long) > _Alignof (unsigned int)
```

and so forth.

Or you could use `malloc` during startup to allocate your array, guaranteeing that it's properly aligned for any type.

Stealing an idea from the comments, you could define a union of array types, something like:

```
#define BYTE_COUNT some_big_number
union arrays {
    unsigned char      ca[BYTE_COUNT];
    unsigned short     sa[BYTE_COUNT  / sizeof (unsigned short)];
    unsigned int       ia[BYTE_COUNT  / sizeof (unsigned int)];
    unsigned long      la[BYTE_COUNT  / sizeof (unsigned long)];
    unsigned long long lla[BYTE_COUNT / sizeof (unsigned long long)];
};
```

Or you could define your arrays for the type of data you want to store in them.

Comment: Another possible solution is to use a union array. Then aliasing should be legal.

Comment: Thanks for that example. So can it be shown from the standard that alignment is the only possible problem? Because I could just do something to ensure proper alignment, like what Veritas said.

Comment: @jack technically an implementation can do anything when optimizing if you don't follow strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @Veritas, so it seems that making an array of the union of the four integer types would have lots of padding, would this work if it were a union of four objects where each where an array of the appropriate number of one of the four integer types?

Comment: @jack: Yes, in an array of unions of integers, each element would have the size of the largest integer type. A union of arrays would work. Creating the array at startup with `malloc` would be simpler. Is the design of your application such that you need large arrays of each of several integer types **and** you're using only one of them at a time? That seems unusual.

Comment: For the recent comment "union of arrays" +1, that is a reasonable approach to solve OP dilemma.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Ya, this is mostly the case. There are some cases where it seems I could be a little more efficient by using one half for one type and the other for a different type, but it doesn't seem like overlapping memory usage that much is really going to work out. But I get most of what I want using the array for different types in a serial fashion.